# TextView not changing when changing Locale of app

Tags: android, locale

I am trying to change the `locale` of application when selecting options from the `onOptionsItemSelected`.

When I try to do so, the language gets successfully changed in the same menu.

However, the `text` in the `TextView` present in the layout doesn't change.

Any help is appreciated.

My MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Locale myLocale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_english) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            setLocale("en");
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_nepal) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You have selected Nepali", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            setLocale("ne");
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void setLocale(String lang) {

        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // refresh your views here
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

My Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.languagesupport">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And both my strings file :

For English:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">languageChange</string>
    <string name="sample_text">Hello World</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="english">English</string>
    <string name="nepal">Nepal</string>
</resources>
```

For Nepali:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">भीमदत्त नगरपालिका</string>
    <string name="action_settings">गृहपृष्ठ</string>
    <string name="sample_text">" विकास क्षेत्रमा पर्ने महाकाली अञ्चल), कञ्चनपुर जिल्लाको स"</string>
    <string name="english">अंग्रेजी</string>
    <string name="nepal">नेपाल</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this use **`finish();`**  after restarting your activity

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

Comment: Nope.. Still the same

Comment: @An08NY in which device your are testing

Comment: Nexus 6P Android emulator

Comment: @An08NY try in real device for text case

Comment: Sorry..Same thing again.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches:

**1. Without Activity restart:**

- Set `android:configChanges="locale"` in your `<activity>` in manifest
- Change your setLocale as follows:

  ```
      private void setLocale(String lang) {
          Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
          Resources res = getResources();
          DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
          Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
          conf.locale = myLocale;
          res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
          getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
          invalidateOptionsMenu();
          onConfigurationChanged(conf);//Add this line
      }
  ```
- Override `onConfigurationChanged()`:

  ```
      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          textView.setText(<your-text>);
          //Any other UI text to change
      }
  ```

This will ensure your locale is changed correctly.

**2. Recreate the activity:**

Instead of

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

**CALL**

`recreate();`

This will cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance.

Comment: This is the first answer that actually describes how to also apply the language change directly, instead of switching to another activity/reloading the active one, so thanks for that! Comments about the code: 1. I'm using a spinner in a `Fragment` to change the language. Calling `getActivity.recreate()` causes some kind of infinite loop (calls `onCreateView()` over and over again) when I try to switch to another fragment. 2. From within a `Fragment` it seems to be perfectly fine to use `res` instead of `getBaseContext().getResources()` and then just call `updateConfiguration()` once.