# Inflating a view with custom locale in Android

Tags: android, locale, layout-inflater

I'm using a LayoutInflater to inflate a custom layout to generate invoices and receipts as Bitmaps then I send them to the printer or export them as png files, Like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_invoice, null);
// Populate the view here...

int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(paperWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

view.layout(0, 0, width, height);

Bitmap reVal = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(reVal);
view.draw(canvas);
```

Now this code works perfectly but it inflates the view in the device's current language. Sometimes i need to generate invoices in other language, Is there any way to inflate that view in custom locale?

Note: I tried to change the locale before inflating the view and reset it afterwards:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.locale = new Locale("fr");
// Inflate the view
// ...
// Reset the locale to the original value
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790295/textview-not-changing-when-changing-locale-of-app/49791381#49791381) ?

Comment: There is no activity to call recreate() on in my case, Plus i don't want to change the app's locale, I just want to inflate that particular view in custom locale.

Comment: I'm inflating the view and drawing it without even showing it on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create localized context with this simple class

```
public class LocalizedContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    public LocalizedContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        } else {
            configuration.locale = locale;
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(
                    configuration,
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
            );
        }

        return new LocalizedContextWrapper(context);
    }
}
```

And use this it like that

```
Context localizedContext = LocalizedContextWrapper.wrap(context, locale);
```

Comment: Can this work with `viewBinding`, i.e. `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());`?

Comment: I think, yes. You can create a localized instance of LayoutInflater like [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50179035/3969880) and use it to inflate your layouts

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to create a new context with custom locale and inflate the view with my new context:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(resources.getConfiguration());
Context customContext = context.createConfigurationContext(config);

Locale newLocale = new Locale("fr");
config.setLocale(newLocale);

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(customContext);
```

(Sorry for asking before doing everything i could).