# After onconfigurationchanged called button click disable

Tags: android

I want to change language dynamically without restart activity. I use onConfigurationChanged but after onconfigurationchange. It works fine every textview changed but allclicklistener makes null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alias);


    switchLang.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // ...
                Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
                newConfig.locale = new Locale("en".toLowerCase());
                onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            } else {
                // ...
                Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
                newConfig.locale = new Locale("tr".toLowerCase());
                onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            }

        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alias);

}
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Do not call `setContentView` inside `onConfigurationChanged`. It will override the previous View which was attached to Activity.

Comment: then nothing change. Same language

Comment: This is the reason why as a default the activity would be restarted. Instead of mimicking this behavior, you should just use it.

Comment: set click listeners again after setcontentview in onConfigurationChanged. But it's always better to let activity restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you called `setContentView` in `onConfigurationChanged` which will Override the previous View attached to Activity, resulting in loss of `onClickListeners`. I would recommend you to `recreate` the activity which is much cleaner approach.

If you still want to achieve language change without restart of activity then you have to `setText` for all your views again in `onConfigurationChanged`. You can check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790295/textview-not-changing-when-changing-locale-of-app/49791381#49791381) to do so. Alternatively, you can set the `onClickListeners` again after `setContentView`