# Change app language in android without adding extra string.xml file

Tags: android, string

I want to convert the in app language of my android application. but i do not want to add any extra `string.xml` file (string-hi.xml). Is it possible to change the language programmatically on button click??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to change the language programmatically on button click

Yes it is possible. Refer to my answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790295/textview-not-changing-when-changing-locale-of-app/49791381#49791381).

> but i do not want to add any extra string.xml file (string-hi.xml)

If you want to change the language for particular you need to have the relative translation with `string-<locale>.xml`. The string won't come from thin air